# Turn T-SQL TOP on or off by parameter via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, t-sql

Is it possible to send a parameter into a powershell sql command (using invoke-sqlcmd) which will either select ALL rows of a query OR just the top 5?

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP $(rowCount) FROM MyTable
```

I wan't to be able to effectively turn on/off this selection in the script. I thought PERCENTAGE would work but I only want to select 5 rows and **PERCENTAGE** would return too many as I am dealing with data-sets consisting of 10s rows and also millions of rows.

I would like to run this script from PowerShell and also in SQL management studio without it complaining about the semantics, but it doesn't seem to like the $() syntax.

Comment: Aside: Note that `top` without `order by` will select the least desirable rows. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The value used in the `top` can already be made dynamic in vanilla `sql`:

```
declare @t table (i int);
insert into @t values(1), (1), (2), (3), (1), (2);

declare @n bigint = 2;

select top (@n) *
from @t;

set @n = 9223372036854775807;  -- Max value available in a BIGINT

select top (@n) *
from @t;
```